# How to use library Django-RQL to filter fields of type 'Time' in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, filtering

I would like using filter in my REST API in my field 'hora' but your type is Time. When I try do query, example: 127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/queimadas/?hora=17:15:33, the error show: "RQL Parsing error."

My task is filter this field 'hora' in beetween of times, like this: ?ge(hora,17:00:00)&le(hora,20:00:00) in url (Following the documentation), but I can not :(

Thanks very much all.

This is documentation the library django-rql - https://django-rql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

My serializers.py:

```
class QueimadaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    satelite = SateliteSerializer(many=False,read_only=True)
    cidade = CidadeSerializer(many=False,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Queimada
        fields = [
        'id',
        'latitude' ,
        'longitude', 
        'data',
        'hora' ,
        'observacao',
        'veracidade', 
        'visitado',
        'satelite', 
        'cidade' 
        ]
```

My views.py:

```
class QueimadasViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Queimada.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QueimadaSerializer
    filter_backends = (RQLFilterBackend,)
    rql_filter_class = QueimadaFilters


    @action(detail=True,methods=['get'])
    def satelite(self,request,pk=None):
        satelite = Satelite.objects.filter(queimada__id=pk)
        self.pagination_class.page_size = 10
        page = self.paginate_queryset(satelite)
   
        if page is not None:
            serializer = SateliteSerializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = SateliteSerializer(satelite, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

My filters.py:

```
class QueimadaFilters(RQLFilterClass):
    MODEL = Queimada
    SELECT = True
    FILTERS = (
    {
        'namespace' : 'cidade',
        'filters':('id','nome'),
        'qs' : SelectRelated('cidade'),

    },
    {
        'filter': 'data',

    },
    {
        'filter': 'hora',
        'custom': True,
        'lookups': {
            FilterLookups.EQ,
            FilterLookups.IN, 
            FilterLookups.I_LIKE,
            FilterLookups.LE,
            FilterLookups.LT,
            FilterLookups.GE, 
            FilterLookups.GT
        },
    },
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommended you to use [django_filters](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html). It's very easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
from rest_framework import filters

class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['username', 'email']
```

install `django-filter`
and declare it in settings.py file so easy to easy